# Verifing if text already exists

Tags: c#, sql

I have a sql table that saves a word and I need to check if that word already exists and I so, I should get a message saying that word already exists. 
Is it possible? If so how should I do it?
I will leave it down below myccode to add the word for the sql, but if you need something else I will provide you without any problem.

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString;
 using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conn))
  {
   sqlConn.Open();
   string sqlQuery = @"INSERT INTO testetiposdestados(CDU_ESTADOS) VALUES(@estados)";
   SqlCommand SQLcm = new SqlCommand();
   SQLcm.Connection = sqlConn;
   SQLcm.CommandText = sqlQuery;
   SQLcm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   SQLcm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estados", textBox1.Text);
   SQLcm.ExecuteNonQuery();
   sqlConn.Close();
}
```

I'm using c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF NOT EXIST` statment like so

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM testetiposdestados 
   WHERE CDU_ESTADOS = @estados)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO testetiposdestados(CDU_ESTADOS) VALUES(@estados)
END
```

Your query will become:

```
string sqlQuery = 
  @"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                    FROM testetiposdestados 
                   WHERE CDU_ESTADOS = @estados) 
    BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO testetiposdestados(CDU_ESTADOS) 
           VALUES (@estados) 
    END";
```

If it inserted successfully it means it was not present in the table already.

Comment: @Josue Figueiredo You have to query a table for identification either your record exists with the same name or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a unique constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CONSTRAINT unq_testetiposdestados_estados
    UNIQUE (CDU_ESTADOS);

INSERT INTO testetiposdestados(CDU_ESTADOS)
    VALUES(@estados);
```

This has the advantage that the *database* ensures that the value is unique, not the *application*.  Hence, this will prevent another `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement from producing a unique value.

Furthermore, this is much safer than the `IF` approach.  That approach is subject to race conditions -- two threads attempting to insert the same value may both succeed.